# Adding an entry in db with Slim and Eloquent

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, eloquent, slim

I'm starting a project using Slim and Eloquent, the connection with my database is working perfectly. My problem is that I can't add an entry to my `tests` table. Here is my Model

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use App\Domain\Test\Test;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewTestAction extends TestAction {

    protected function action(): Response {

        $data = $this->request->getParsedBody();
        $test = new Test;
        $test->id = $data["id"];
        $test->txt = $data["txt"];
        $test->save();
        return $this->respondWithData($test);

    }

}
```

It works if I put the values directly in the code, like this

```
$test->id = 1;
$test->txt = "test";
```

I'm using Postman to test my code, I got that Error

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"error": {
    "type": "SERVER_ERROR",
       "description": "ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type null on line 18 in file /home/fiona/my_micro_service/my_micro_services/src/Application/Actions/Test/NewTestAction.php."
    }
}
```

How can I insert a basic entry to my db ?

Update with my table structure and Model

```
    TABLE tests
   (id int(11),
   txt VARCHAR(255),
    updated_at date,
    created_at date);
```

Model :

```
namespace App\Domain\Test;
                        
class Test extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
}
```

Comment: Please post your Model Class and your database table structure would be also helpful.

Comment: Try to debug it because `$data` is null as per the error you mentioned. Print: `$data` to see why it's returning blank. could be the reason `getParsedBody` is not returning the expected result.

Comment: @odan line 18 is `$test->txt = $data["txt"];`

Comment: @ParminderSingh Yes data seems to be null, I don't understand why

Comment: @spock Your Model is empty. You need to set it up: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Try `$this->request->getContent()` or `$this->request->all()`

Comment: @ParminderSingh I get `Call to undefined method Slim\\Psr7\\Request::getContent()` for both

Comment: For slim v3, getParsedBody or getBody should work: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html
Which version do you have?

Comment: @ParminderSingh I have Slim 4

Comment: Ok see this: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html#the-request-body you will get help from there.